# Blocking subdomains - google oauth and nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, oauth, nginx-reverse-proxy, google-authenticator

I have an ELB setup on AWS which sends requests to a service that is hosted on an ec2 instance. On this instance, i have oauth 2 proxy setup(https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy) which receives requests and forwards to application.

Current setup
Google auth config file

```
http_address = "0.0.0.0:8081"
upstreams = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:4411/"
]
```

Now i want to add nginx to this setup in order to block a subdomain. I want to route google auth proxy to nginx which then filters out some requests and allows some requests to application. Could someone point me to how this should be done? In which port should i run nginx on and how my upstream and http_address will get modified?

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify why you would put nginix behind "oauth2_proxy" module?

Ideally, traffic should hit nginx first and then should flow to oauth2_proxy.

Comment: That would be okay too! Could you recommend how we can do that?

Comment: Can you confirm if you have tried the steps mentioned in this link? https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy